# Unable to apply method "read" to TdmsFile from nptdms

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, labview

I have been using the `nptdms` module to do analysis of TDMS files without issue for several years. Recently, I got an error when trying to read a TDMS file for the first time. I import `TdmsFile` from `nptdms`:

`from nptdms import TdmsFile`

I try to read it:

`tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(path_to_my_tdms_file)`

and then get the following error:

`type object 'TdmsFile' has no attribute 'read'`

I am using  python v3.6.10, with Anaconda and the nptdms v0.12.0.

Comment: "

I have been using the nptdms module to do analysis of TDMS files without issue for several years. Recently, I got an error when trying to read a TDMS file for the first time." I don't understand; what were you doing with those TDMS files for all those years without reading them?

Comment: I was reading them, using the .read() method. i haven't used nptdms for a few months and just noticed the error now.

Comment: If your code was working before and isn't now, there is no way that anyone else is going to be able to reproduce that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are referring to [exists in the current documentation](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html?highlight=TdmsFile#nptdms.TdmsFile.read) so it would make sense to

1. Restart the virtual environment (close cmd line; start again; `conda activate <name of your env>`).

If this does not help...

2. Reinstall the package:

   `conda remove nptdms`

   `conda install nptdms`

(the exact commands may differ depending on your environment).

If this does not help, create a fresh conda environment and install from scratch and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this issue is recent and real. A re-install of nptdms via pip does appear to solve it. (even though pip claimed it was up to date as of version 0.17.1)